# Take random item from list in "for" loop

Tags: kotlin

I have a list containing a random element from another list
`var test = listOf<String>("Blah blah " + list1.shuffled().take(1)[0] + " blah blah")`
A bigger list `biglist`, containing  a smaller lists like `test`
Then, there is a "for" loop, in which I am filling stringbuilder with random lists from `biglist`

```
    var list3 = listOf<String>("Something something1","Something something2")
    var list2 = listOf<String>("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4")
    var list = listOf<String>("Blah " + list2.shuffled().take(1)[0] + " blah")
    var sb = StringBuilder ()
    var biglist = listOf<String>()
    if (...) biglist += list
    if (...) biglist += list3.get(0)
    if (...) biglist += list3.get(1)
    for (i in 0 until 4) {
        sb.append(biglist.shuffled().take(1)[0] + "\n")
        i + 1
    }
    
    println(sb)
```

So, on output, I want to see something like this:

```
Something something1
Blah item2 blah
Something something2
Blah item4 blah
```

Instead I am having this:

```
Something something1
Blah item2 blah
Something something2
Blah item2 blah
```

My problem is, that in `sb`, `test` list will every time contain the same item, randomly picked at the beginning of code from `list1`
I have kind of solved it, putting creation of the `biglist` INTO the `for` loop (and clearing it after sb.append), but it just make my code looks even shittier (and slower?)

Maybe there is a better solution to this?
Thanks

Comment: This is very unclear. Post a minimal complete code showing the problem. Tell precisely what its output should be, and what it is instead.

Comment: @JBNizet yes sir, edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your evaluation of `list` inside the loop:

```
var list3 = listOf("Something something1", "Something something2")
var list2 = listOf("item1", "item2", "item3", "item4")

var sb = StringBuilder()

(0..4).forEach {
    var list = listOf("Blah ${list2.shuffled().first()} blah")

    var biglist = listOf<String>()
    biglist += list // left out the if statements for simplicity
    biglist += list3.get(0)
    biglist += list3.get(1)
    sb.append(biglist.shuffled().first() + "\n")
}

println(sb)
```

A few notes:

- use a range and `forEach` to do it multiple times (since you don't need the loop variable `i` anyways
- `take(1)[0]` can be replaced by `first()`
- use a string template to build the element of `list`
- you don't need the type parameter for `list2` and `list3`, the type (String) can be inferred from the list's elements
- if your list becomes big calling `shuffle` will be a waste of resources, especially because you are only interested in one random element of that list. Use this extension function instead: `fun List<*>.randomElement() = this[Random().nextInt(this.size)]`

Comment: i didnt test it yet, but the `biglist` having lots of strings, and this `for` loop is going to repeat about 1000 times, and all this on mobile phones
so im a little bit worried about performance troubles

Comment: @roman: If you want more performance, don't use shuffle. Generate an index within the elements range and access the element directly.